# How to avoid retrieving instance to update field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these lines :

```
my_field = days

user_model = User.objects.get(pk=2)
```

I want to do something like this :

```
user_model.my_field += 7
```

I can do it using `update(my_field=new_value)` keyword instead of `get()` and then modifying the instance, but I'm not sure how I can avoid calling `get()` since, for each instance, I need multiple existing values from the fields to determine the new value to update the field with. I'm still trying out `django`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). You can use this with queries and with (or without) `update` and everything will take place at the SQL level.

Example from the docs:

```
from django.db.models import F
reporter = Reporters.objects.filter(name='Tintin')
reporter.update(stories_filed=F('stories_filed') + 1)
```